# Angular commands not working

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded my Angular-cli, when I try to use Angular commands:

```
ng g c appliances
ng g m appliances\appliances --routing
```

Error

```
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 930
```

Comment: Would you share the actual command you are trying to run in the terminal? What you have provided is not much to go on...

Comment: I have added the commands

Comment: @Narm It was that simple, eh? Thank you.

Comment: You got some invalid entry in `package.json`

Comment: Also, you might want to tell us which version of Angular CLI you are using. We can assume you mean 6.0.0 because that is the most recent. But, just to be sure do a: ng --version